# SSRS Error "sys.webforms.pageRequestmanagerservererrorexception"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, webforms, sql-server-2008-r2

Error "sys.webforms.pageRequestmanagerservererrorexception" appears when I select all the list inside a drop down in a SSRS report. When i select a few items, report works fine. I think I need to maximize the data limit being retrieved through http. Need instructions on how to do this.

Comment: If you are using a query string to send params then you are possibly hitting the max url size configured in IIS.

Comment: I understand the reason why its causing the error, however I was hoping an explanation in details about how change settings on windows server or SQL server??

Comment: What version  of .net are you using.

Comment: the .net version is 4.5

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, is there any posibility where I can perform this change on server, if yes then do I need to perform on SQL server or Windows server??

Comment: I mean instead of updating web.config file in an App, is there any chance I could do some setting on server?? cause this is affecting more than one application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property below in the web.config section of your web app to override the default size:

```
HttpRuntimeSection.MaxQueryStringLength Property 

<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="3260" maxRequestLength="3048"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, is there any posibility where I can perform this change on server, if yes then do I need to perform on SQL server or Windows server??

Comment: I mean instead of updating web.config file in an App, is there any chance I could do some setting on server?? cause this is affecting more than one application.

Comment: I bet you need to look into the requestLimits in IIS. This can be set at a root level config. -->  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits